# Audio Injector stereo soundcard is preventing boot

Tags: boot, audio, hat, failure, activity-led

I recently bought a [Audioinjector stereo soundcard HAT](http://www.audioinjector.net/rpi-hat) to stream sound on my raspberry pi running Raspbian. I went to their website and installed the .deb installer file and ran it with `audioInjector-setup.sh` and then rebooted as it told me. However, it failed to boot, as it only shows a black screen, and the green LED keeps flashing steady on the rpi. Am I doing something wrong?

NOTE: I am using a Raspberry pi 3B with Raspbeian running on it.

[image: Audioinjector stereo soundcard]
Picture of audioinjector stereo soundcard

Comment: Contact the supplier

Comment: What Raspberry Pi model do you use? Does it boot without any driver software installed?

Comment: I am using a RPI 3B version. It would boot normally without any drivers until I downloaded this one on the Audioinjector website.

Comment: I just got the same thing on the RPi Zero with their Audio Injector Zero soundcard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a significant hardware issue, this may stop the Pi from loading. Make sure the sound card is plugged in correctly to the Pi's GPIO header. If you plug the card in and the Pi boots (before you have run the software setup) then it is most likely that it is not a hardware issue.

For software issues, perhaps it is easier to manually setup the card, which is pretty simple.

To get this sound card to work you can edit the config.txt file by hand.
Try using the nano editor to edit the config.txt file which is in the /boot directory :

```
nano /boot/config.txt
```

Comment out the dtparam=audio=on line, by putting a "#" in front like so :

```
#dtparam=audio=on
```

Make sure the Audio Injector device tree is loaded at boot time by adding this line to the config.txt file :

```
dtoverlay=audioinjector-wm8731-audio
```

Now reboot.